# Microsoft SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is NULL for numeric types

Tags: t-sql, information-schema

I want to select on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the size of numeric columns. I can see the size is set in the properties in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` does not have this information. Is there some other table where I can get this information for numeric columns?

For example, I have a column defined as `INT` with a size of 4, but  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is `NULL`.

How do I get this size in a select statement?

Comment: Try using `sys.columns` instead - in that case, `INT` columns are shown with a `max_length` of 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` then you will have to infer it from the data-type for the integer-based columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
        (Select Length From sys.systypes s Where s.name = c.DATA_TYPE)
        ) As Max_Len
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
```

You'll have to do extra work to some of the other types though (like NUMERIC, DECIMAL, etc..).